# Pandas ImportError VSCode MacOS

Tags: python, pandas, macos, visual-studio-code, pip

I've installed pandas with pip and when I run my program in the terminal it works. But when I run it with the gray arrow (top right corner) in VSCode it says:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/diego/Documents/Progra/Clase20/actividad01.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/diego/Documents/Progra/Clase20/actividad01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.033 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that `VSCode` is not using the same `python interpreter` as the one you are using in the terminal. In general it is better to create a `virtual environment` and install your libraries in it. Then you configure the IDE to use the project related virtual environment. All can be done via VSCode.

[Here are some details about using Python environments in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the source of the installation tool "`pip`". Its source determines the magnification position of the module we install. (`pip --version` or `pip3 --version`)

   [image]

   (If the terminal display is not the current environment, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+`  to open the VSCode terminal, it will automatically enter the current environment)
2. Install the module.
3. Check the installation package. Use "`pip show pandas`" to check whether the module is successfully installed in the currently selected VSCode environment:

   [image]
4. Run:

   [image]